# How to update iPhone without wifi?

Tags: iphone, wifi, security, software-update

I need to update iPhone to get important security updates. I do not have access to a wifi connection, and even when I do, cellular is *much* more performant: in Australia, about 20 times better download on 5G than on broadband (250 Mbps vs ~25 Mbps).

How an I work around Apple's archaic restriction that makes updating an iPhone impossible without wifi?

Comment: Have you tried connecting the iPhone to a computer and update via the Finder on a Mac or through iTunes on a PC?

Comment: You might try setting up a cellular-based wifi connection for the iPhone by acquiring a 2nd mobile connection and the necessary equipment if everything else fails.

Answer (score 3):

Try with iTunes with a laptop (where you make an Access Point from your phone).

So PC is connected via 5G via phone, and then you download the update and install it via iTunes.